# ingest streaming data from API to Bigquery in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to ingest data from an api in stream to bigquery.

I guess that the best option is to use cloud dataflow in order to ingest this data into bigquery, but I don't know how to extract the data from the API: https://developer.tomtom.com/traffic-api

Can I extract the data in the same dataflow pipeline or I have to create an instance and extract the data from there to  cloud PUB/SUB and then use dataflow to move this data to bigquery?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on the usecase. You can use the source directly with dataflow if it has a source connector for that data. Otherwise, it would be easiest to first get the data to pubsub and then use a dataflow pipeline to do what you need to do.

Comment: Could you specify what is the API, you want to ingest data from? Is it also Google product or external one, such as AWS?

Comment: The API is that one: https://developer.tomtom.com/traffic-api

Comment: Thanks for the sharing more details. Api requires query parameters. How are you planning to get those query parameters?

Comment: I only need to know if I have to run it in a instance and inget it to a Pub/Sub subscription or I can get the data directly from a dataflow job

Comment: It's not clear to me if you have set of initial data to begin with which you will be using to query the api. The data can be list of city or userid etc. which you will be passing to dataflow to work upon. If you have more details on the source of input data, then we can explore as to how you can use dataflow.

Comment: agreed with Ankur. If you want a streaming pipeline that queries the API periodically, you can develop a ParDo with state and timers that will query your API periodically and produce new data. (see https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) - if you share more about *how* you want to read data from tomtom, we can try to help build an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my assumption is you have an api, from which you want to send data to bigquery. Since you cannot stream directly the API you have to hit on a batch interval it can be hourly or minute based on the API limitations.

You can have a job to read data from this API, and pump into PUB/SUB and use a data flow to pump data to BQ. Or you can use the job directly to pump data to BQ. it's up to your data volume/backup strategy and business requirements.